# Ajax read json to url web site

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

[image]

I am getting have correct json and read ajax get by json after that code generate response array.

I have problem with UTF-8 Turkish Character.

How to fix this.

Comment: "I have problem with UTF-8 Turkish Character" so what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

the edit is awful get your original question back it's clearer i think.

Comment: hmmm while you don't have enough reps for commenting, I don't believe your statement is important enough :3